# Reg Shared Memory Design

Tags: ipc, shared-memory

For my project requirement,

I need help on designing Inter Processs communication for the below scenario.

There are 4 Source process wants to communicate with 1 destination process using IPC.

I have selected Shared Memory as a mechanism for this purpose. I am ending up with design issues like

1) Should i have to use 4 shared memory for each process ? or should i use single memory ?

2) If i use 4 memory , then i have to go for 4 synchronisation object separately to synchronise source and destination process. In future , one more process comes , then i have edit destimation process source code which i dont want to do that.

3) Should my destination be multi threaded ? becoz i am using  more source process..

please guide me in that...

Answer (score 0):

1) Should i have to use 4 shared memory for each process ? or should i use single memory ?

Not required. Create one shared memory segment, attach with all processes which you want to access.

2) If i use 4 memory , then i have to go for 4 synchronisation .....

probably you can use semaphore to synchronize the access to shared memory segment.

3) Should my destination be multi threaded ? becoz i am using more source process..

Depends. If you use multithreaded environment, you may not need shared memory segment, rather you can use shared data [ ie: heap ], and again use any synchronization method to avoid race condition.

Hope it helps!!!.